# Assign html content in a variable ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to assign html content of a component in a variable but it is giving error.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import Relatorio1Page from './relatorio1';

/**
 * Generated class for the RelatoriosPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-relatorios',
    templateUrl: 'relatorios.html',
})

export class RelatoriosPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad RelatoriosPage');
    }

    @aViewChild('conteudo') conteudo: ElementRef;
    public relatorio1(){
        //the objective is to fill this variable with relatorio1Page inner html
        let conteudo = Relatorio1Page.innerHTML; 
    }

}
```

Hierarchy between pages is

pages
-relatorio1
--Relatorio1Page.ts
-relatorios
--RelatoriosPage.ts

Could you help me?

Comment: What is your exact error message? When are you calling `relatorio1()`? Have you tried to access `Relatorio1Page.nativeElement.innerHTML`?

Comment: Please share the html file also. Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can´t use that page as a component?